# JavaScript Incrementing a number in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to increment a value in a array when a link is pressed in JavaScript

i Used the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var i=0;
 var numbers = new Array();


 function go(val){

 numbers[i]=val;
 i++;

 alert(numbers[i]);

 }

</script>
```

**Called the Function like this**

```
<a href='javascript:go(1)' </a>
```

***but always the alert prompts me 'undefined'***

Comment: Your `<a>` markup is invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you increment "i"

```
i++;
```

right *before* you put up the alert! Thus "i" will alwuays refer to the *next* array slot to use, not the one you just populated.

You could change the alert to use "i-1"

```
alert(numbers[i - 1]);
```

Comment: Or move the increment, e.g. `alert(numbers[i++]);`

Comment: This assumes that the intention is to alert the variable that was passed in - it's a *possibility*, but it doesn't leap out of the page as being the obvious intention (it's pretty useless in this particular case).

Comment: @Andrzej yes I agree - I suspect that the `alert()` is just there as a debugging aid; if so it would probably be good to show "i" as well.

Answer (score 7):

The alert is correct -- before you do your alert, you incremented `i`.  You're looking at the *next* element after the one you just entered.

After calling the method once, your array looks like this:

```
numbers[0] = 1;
numbers[1] = undefined;
```

and `i == 1`.

After calling it again, the array looks like:

```
numbers[0] = 1;
numbers[1] = 1;
numbers[2] = undefined;
```

and `i == 2`.

Hopefully you can see that this method will *always* alert `undefined`

Comment: I expanded on your example to show multiple invocations, since it sounds like the OP might have expected it to work on subsequent tries ("but **always** the alert prompts me...").  If you don't like this, feel free to revert.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting `numbers[0] = 1` and then incrementing `i` which becomes `1` so `alert(numbers[1])` is undefined, because it **is** undefined.

Do the `alert` before you increment. Also, use `onclick` or even better unobtrusively attach the event handlers in JS, not in the HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does that because you:

1. Create a completely empty array, and a pointer at `0`.
2. When the function is called, you set the current pointer value to whatever was passed in...
3. ...and then increment the pointer, so it's now pointing past the end of all the elements.
4. **Now** you look at the element in the array that's being pointed at, which **has** to be `undefined` because of the way you're managing the `i` pointer.

What were you hoping for this to do, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't even match the code... or the code doesn't match the question?

"I want to increment a value in a array"

Your code is not incrementing the value, it's incrementing the index!

```
function go(val){
  numbers[i]=val;
  i++;
}
```

(where **i** is the index of the next undefined array element) is just the same as

```
numbers.push(val);
```

and if you need **i** to equal what will be the index of the next undefined array element then

```
i = numbers.length;
```

To increment the *value* you would have to first have numeric values for some array elements; then your function would need the index of which value to increment

```
var numbers = [0,0,0,0];

function go(i){
  numbers[i]++;
}

// testing

go(1);
go(3);
go(1);

alert(numbers);
```

will show 0,2,0,1

But if your entire goal is to put a value into a new element on the end of an array then just use .push()

and .length will tell you how many elements there are; there is no need to increment an **i**